# How to show parent/child relationship in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, parent-child

I'm using jQuery datatable, passing data from Laravel controller to html view and using `foreach()` I'm iterating through the parent child array and hiding child's initially and showing them by clicking parent row, I'm showing 25 rows per page but if 1st parent having 15 child's and 2nd having 20 then datatable only showing initial 25 rows rest remain hidden even on next page.

So how can I reset dynamic page length per page depend on child count